# Verify a bare Git repository has data

Tags: git, git-bare

How does one verify that files were pushed to a bare repository correctly? Since bare repositories have no working tree, you obviously can't do a simple `git log` because it isn't picked up as a git repo.

I realize there are solutions like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864421/preview-files-in-a-bare-repository/13865676#13865676), but I'd like to know how to do it using the command line.

Comment: Note that I'm not looking to see *what* is in it; simply that there *is* something in it (i.e. not an empty bare repo)

Comment: `git log` doesn't even look at the workspace, it should work just fine in a bare repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and use [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote):

```
 git ls-remote http://www.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git

 # or, also a bare repo
 git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git
```

As long as it doesn't return just [the emtpy tree SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309), that should mean there are commits in that upstream repo.

Comment: Perfect! This worked perfectly. Note that this also works with `ssh://` protocol URLs.

Answer (score 3):

`git log` works just fine.  Bare repositories are still recognized as repositories.  Obviously.  :)

```
git@koiru /var/git/repositories/sanpera.git $ ls
total 37k
-rw-r--r--   1 git nogroup 1.2k Mar  1 06:00 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--   1 git nogroup   23 Sep 14  2011 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x   2 git nogroup 4.1k Sep 14  2011 branches/
-rw-------   1 git nogroup  236 Jun 12  2012 config
-rw-r--r--   1 git nogroup   34 Jun 12  2012 description
drwxr-xr-x   2 git nogroup 4.1k Jun 12  2012 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x   2 git nogroup 4.1k Sep 14  2011 info/
drwxr-xr-x 222 git nogroup 4.1k Sep  9 06:00 objects/
drwxr-xr-x   5 git nogroup 4.1k Oct 18  2011 refs/

git@koiru /var/git/repositories/sanpera.git $ git log
commit a60f2ad3cc118eb7fd290be56448bcef82fe8252
Author: Eevee <git@veekun.com>
Date:   Sun Sep 2 18:22:50 2012 -0700

    Stub a few more tests.

...
```

Comment: I'm getting a `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: And yea, the "obviously" bit was a bit snarky. I should have worded that better ;)

Comment: having no `HEAD` sounds like a pretty good indication that you _don't_ have any data.  check the `refs/heads` directory; that lists all the branches.  if it's empty, you got nothin'.

Comment: VonC's answer *did* show there was a correct branch. I had forgotten to pull all of the branches before I pushed back to another remote.